# Group Policy Object (GPO) - bypass Computer Configuration for a specific AD Group (Admins)

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-server-2019

is it possible to bypass a GPO "Computer Configuration" (Firewall Settings) for a specific AD Group ?

We want a specific AD group to be able to disable the firewall. Currently this GPO applies to users and admins. I added this admin group in the Local\Administrators, but I have the same result...

I also tested the loopback policy but it does not change anything.

Do you know of a more appropriate way to proceed?

Many thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to bypass a GPO "Computer Configuration" (Firewall
> Settings) for a specific AD Group?

It is not possible. You can exclude specific computers from having the policy applied, but you can't exclude computer settings from being applied to specific users.